# Rebuilding an giant index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a problem with an rather big (Non-Clustered) index ~6 T on one of my tables in my SQL Server database. According to the "Disk Usage by Partition" report only around ~2 T are actually used. As we are constantly inserting into the database it is unsurprising that the data gets pretty fragmented. So the next step should be to rebuild the index.

Here my problem is though that the disk is rather full with only around 400 GB of free space. When I try to rebuild this index it task quite some time and fails then. (I missed writing down the exact error message but it basically sad that it failed due to missing space). Also the complete disk was full afterwards.

Is there a way to still rebuild this index?
Is it may be the solution is to delete the index and just recreate it? (I guess this should work but as I inherited the Database with many of its configuration I don´t want to break anything). Or does this have any consequences I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

If the table (or rather: index) is partitioned, then you could consider rebuilding at partition level.

Also, since this is a non-clustered index, you could drop and then create the index. ALTER INDEX REBUILD will create a new index, and *then* drop the old one. By droppring the index first, you don't need double space (old and new).

Based on your insert pattern, rebuild might not buy you a lot, though. If you insert "all over the place", then you will get splits after your rebuild and after a while you are back to where you started.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to still rebuild this index?

Are you doing offline or online index rebuild. Offline takes less space than online but I have a hunch that it would still fail. Plus only enterprise edition has parallel online index rebuild feature.

Have you tried reorganizing the index it takes a lot less pace but the transaction log would still fill with information about reorganize so keep a look on Trn log files of the database. The good thing is it is lightweight, it works on leaf level of the index and as it moves it fixes physical fragmentation. If anytime you feel it it taking long time, cancel it, start it later, it will start from where it left. This is not case with rebuild, its kind of all or none operation. Killing index rebuild causes a rollback which would be nightmare for such a big index.

Plus I would suggest you to read [Paul Randal's blog on Index Maintenance](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-19-misconceptions-around-index-rebuilds-allocation-bulk_logged-mode-locking/)

Answer (score 2):

Good points made so far that should directly address your immediate problem. I wanted to add the following few points to consider which *may* be helpful in the long term:

1. Are you sure the index is actually being used enough to warrant its existence? You can use the DMV [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check the frequency at which the index is used for seeks, scans, and lookups. The [Index usage information](https://www.sqlshack.com/gathering-sql-server-indexes-statistics-and-usage-information/) section of this article goes into further details on how to analyze how useful an index actually is. But basically if there's a small number of seeks, scans, and lookups then you may find the index is not very useful to even keep around.
2. Additionally, depending on the queries the index supports, maybe a [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=A%20filtered%20index%20is%20an,of%20rows%20in%20the%20table.) would be a better choice and could consume a significant amount of less space.
3. Finally, have you looked into [compressing your index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-ver15), which may save you a significant amount of space too?